# Repeting texture rather than scaling texture? How to fix it

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor

Trying to add an image texture on my mesh, and i UV unwrap it like this. 
[image]
but it turns out to be 
[image]
Not sure what is wrong with this. Have no clue.
Here is my Node setup(i am using backfacing to make a plane have two material on both side)
[image]

Comment: Remake a new logo file ,and made it jped file. now it works...

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the image repeating, set the Image Texture node from ‘Repeat’ to ‘Clip’. This tells the node to only output a single image within the 0.0 -> 1.0 range.

Comment: What do you mean by set from Repeat to clip, is there any check box or option??

Comment: @Richard On the Image Texture node you’ll see the various settings for the node - currently Color, Linear, Flat, Repeat, Single Image. Click on the Repeat one - this sets how the image should behave outside the normal coordinate range - you should see an option for ‘Clip’ - choose that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you check Min and Max in each *Vector > Mapping* node, then the image will not repeat.

Comment: Thank you, think this would help many people!

Comment: @Richard Thanks! Glad to help. If you liked my answer, please consider upvoting and accepting it (the up-arrow and check mark on my post’s left-hand side). I’d appreciate it!

Comment: I really appreciate! but i dont have enough reputation to vote... sorry for that